# How to write row by row into a BLOB

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I have a package that row by row writes to an external file by using the UTL_FILE. It there a way to do the same thing row by row but inserting directly into a BLOB column of a table?

Oracle version 10g

Thanks in advance

Mark

Comment: Check the package [DBMS_LOB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#BABDDFDH)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an XLS in a LOB column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66602694/how-to-create-an-xls-in-a-lob-column)